# intellij fails to push to some of my github repositories

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I can easily push code to repositories under organization, but cannot push code to repositories I created.

I get

```
Failed with error: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/__username__/__project_name__.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

using the git cli, everything is fine.

also tried:

- using token instead of username/password
- using ssh and https urls for remote origin

how can I resolve this?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/https-cloning-errors/

Answer (score 2):

try change git ssh executable to native.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple. Generate keys on your device

---

Simply follow those steps and you will set up your ssh key in no time:

- Generate a new ssh key (or skip this step if you already have a key)
  `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your@email"`
- Once you have your key set in `home/.ssh` directory (or `Users/<your user>.ssh` under windows), open it and copy the content

---

#### How to add sh key to github account?

- Login to github account
- Click on the rancher on the top right (Settings)
  [image: github account settigns]
- Click on the `SSH keys`
  [image: ssh key section]
- Click on the `Add ssh key`
  [image: Add ssh key]
- Paste your key and save

And you all set to go :-)